# Tag synonym request: [processing.org] -> [processing]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

[processing.org](/questions/tagged/processing.org) - 65 questions, wiki excerpt but no wiki

[processing](/questions/tagged/processing) - 427 questions, full wiki

The wiki excerpts are nearly identical, and [processing](/questions/tagged/processing) is a more popular/well-maintained tag, so I suggest merging [processing.org](/questions/tagged/processing.org) -> [processing](/questions/tagged/processing).

Comment: You are the tag cleanup man aren't you! +1 to you good sir

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163975/what-to-do-with-the-processing-tag

Answer (score 3):

It would rather be better to change [processing.org](/questions/tagged/processing.org) in [processing-language](/questions/tagged/processing-language).
[processing](/questions/tagged/processing) is being used on questions like [Lego Mindstorms: gnu noSuchPortException after severl successful attempts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14205615/lego-mindstorms-gnu-nosuchportexception-after-severl-successful-attempts) which has nothing to share with Processing.

Answer (score 2):

They should indeed be synonym, but the processing tag needs to be watched closely, as it's highly ambiguous, as [Save a specific part of a huge text file (over 2GB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507297/save-a-specific-part-of-a-huge-text-file-over-2gb) shows; in that case, processing is used for a question about processing a text file.